# How do I get rid of Blank spaces?

Tags: php, string

```
$data = "google,bing,searchengine,seo,search";

$exp = explode(",",$data);

$filtr = array("google","bing");

$fdat = str_replace($filtr,"",$data);

$clean = implode(",",$fdat);

echo $clean;
```

this gives out put `,,searchengine,seo,search`

How can I get rid of first two blank commas?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better get the difference of your splitted arrays `$exp` minus `$filtr`:

```
$clean = implode(',', array_diff($exp, $filtr));
```

This will also avoid the chance that you will only remove a substring of another word like when removing `car` from `bike,car,carpet` should result in `bike,carpet` and not in `bike,pet`.

And if you want to allow whitespace before and after each word, consider using [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) and [`preg_split`](http://php.net/preg_split):

```
$exp = preg_split('/\s*,\s*/', trim($data));
```

`trim` will remove any preceding and trailing whitespace and the pattern for `preg_split` allows whitespace surrounding the comma too.

Answer (score 0):

I'm getting an error when trying this code you did. You can use the following to remove google & bing (that are in an array) from a comma separated string:

`$data = "google,bing,searchengine,seo,search";

$exp = explode(",",$data);

$filtr = array("google","bing");

$diff = array_diff($exp, $filtr);

$clean = implode(",",$diff);

echo $clean;`

Answer (score 0):

Your piece of code could also look like this:

```
$data = "google,bing,searchengine,seo,search";

$exp = explode(",",$data);

$filtr = array("google","bing");

foreach ($exp as $key => $item) {
  if (in_array($key, $filtr)) unset($exp[$key]);
}

$clean = implode(",",$exp);

echo $clean;
```

Its useful when there is few items in $data. For big arrays it would need optimizing.

Answer (score 0):

You would be better if checking the value within a loop like so:

```
$data = "google,bing,searchengine,seo,search";
$exp = explode(",",$data);
$filtr = array("google","bing");

foreach($exp as $k => $v)
{
    if(in_array($v,$filtr))
    {
        unset($ext[$k]);
    }
}
$clean = implode(",",$ext);
echo $clean;
```